# Creating Batch Files That Get the Author and title

Tags: batch-file, properties

I was wondering if there was a way to get the author and title properties of word,  power point and excel documents.

I want to run this on various computers so i don't really want to have to install libs on each one (so i thought running a batch file would be best.

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting file properties using a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494616/getting-file-properties-using-a-batch-file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this previous question: [Getting file properties using a batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494616/getting-file-properties-using-a-batch-file)