# What is the batch command to find out the author of a file?

Tags: batch-file, windows-7

I am writing a batch script to check a group of files and provide who saved the file last (the author). Is there a batch command that will give you the author of the file? I can find out when the file was last modified but not who it was modified by.

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=1-9" %%a in ('dir /q^|find ".txt" /i') do echo %%e
```

;) if not working, count the number of columns and adjust %%e accordingly. use % not %% at the command line

Comment: Thanks for the response, I assume you replace .txt with the name of the file? As it stands I get "%%a is unexpected at this time"

Comment: replace the .txt with the file or part of file name that you want to match. replace the %% with % for use on the command line. ;)

Comment: I'm trying for example:

for /f "tokens=1-5" %a in ('dir /q^|find "C:\users\westme\test directory" /i') do echo %e

But its outputting nothing?

Comment: don't use the full path, run this in the dir you have the file in and use only the file name and extension.

Answer (score 0):

There is no batch command to tell you who modified a given file, like a text file.

Answer (score 0):

How about

> dir /Q

You can find out more "dir" options by typing "dir /?"

Comment: That's the owner of a file, not who edited it last, right?  I don't have multiple users so can't check, but that's how I understood it.

Comment: I was looking for who last edited it. With Dir /Q how would I get it to only return the username and not the other data surrounding it?

Comment: This is a comment to the "for" replay above since I cannot post there: You can also do 'find "<machine-name>" ' since the owner is printed out as "<machine-name>\<user-name>".

Answer (score 0):

You could use the DIR's /q command, but that only displays the owner of the file.

e.g.: `dir /q` or `dir /q | find "docx"` to find a specific extention or name of the document.

Comment: Here's a simlar question. Looks like you can do it with a VB script :)
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6494616/getting-file-properties-using-a-batch-file